# Can I get farmbucks without spending real money?

Tags: farmville

I've been playing for a couple months now and there's a lot of animals, plants and trees that require farmbucks. I'm level 12 and I am very confused.

Is there a way to get farmbucks without buying them with real money?

Comment: Welcome to the freemium trap.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes if you look below your farm in the ads there is an add for do this activity and earn "whatever" amount of farm bucks, but very rarely pop up. Other than that, no.

Comment: "ad" for "advertisement"